# How to 301 redirect htaccess with variable in different path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm rebuilding a site and have a big list of category url's which have to be redirected to a new category url.

Old url: http://www.example.com/channels/5/category1/

New url: http://www.example.com/categories/category1/

How to accomplish this with an htaccess 301 redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} $channels/5/([\w-]+)/$
RewriteRule ^ example.com/categories/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single 301 redirect rule as your first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/channels/[0-9]+/(.+)$ /categories/$1
```